# How do I add a guard to something when there's multiple answers?

Tags: haskell, guard

I'm completely new to any sort of programming/coding and know nothing about it and only recently started learning coding on Haskell. I am learning about guards and know that they work for Booleans (I'm only just starting to grasp what they are now too), but am currently stuck. I was given a function that converted marks into grades:

```
data Grade  = Fail | Pass | Credit | Distinction | HighDistinction
  deriving Show

type Mark = Int

markToGrade :: Mark -> Grade 
markToGrade mark
 | mark >= 80 && mark <= 100 = HighDistinction
 | mark >= 70 && mark < 80 = Distinction
 | mark >= 60 && mark < 70 = Credit
 | mark >= 50 && mark < 60 = Pass
 | mark >=  0 && mark < 50 = Fail
```

And was told to create a guard that, when given a number below 0 or above 100 in the terminal, would give the message "markToGrade: Not a valid mark"

However I tried putting all sorts of different things like setting the limit between 0 and 100 using => and <= and using "otherwise" but nothing worked, I kept coming up with parse errors (I also don't know what those are) and ended up making an account here. If anyone can help me on how to make a guard for this function I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance. (Also as an extra, what does "deriving show" mean?)

Comment: It would be helpful if you not only stated that you have tried something with something, but also the exact code that you have tried. Let us also know what the (exact) outcome was of your tests and what you would prefer instead.

Comment: For more open-ended beginner Haskell questions, where you need more tutorial-type instruction and may have follow-up questions, the [Haskell Questions](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskellquestions) page on Reddit is generally better than Stack Overflow. This site is most helpful when you can post a specific code example that you’ve tried and specific error messages or incorrect results. It’s also helpful to search “stack overflow <topic>” before posting, using a search engine that works instead of the SO site search. The `#haskell` chat channel on Freenode chat may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> And was told to create a guard that, when given a number below 0 or above 100 in the terminal, would give the message "markToGrade: Not a valid mark"

This is essentially telling you to have a fall back case. In pseudo-code, they're telling you to change this:

```
if color == blue
    print blue_text
elseif color == red
    print red_star
end
# ops, what if the color was green?
```

to this

```
if color == blue
    print blue_text
elseif color == red
    print red_star
else
    error("we don't have this color sorry")
end
```

To do this in Haskell you can just add another case to your code,

```hs
 | otherwise = error "markToGrade: Not a valid mark"
```

Notice that `otherwise` is exactly a synonym for `True`.

> I'm completely new to any sort of programming/coding and know nothing about it and only recently started learning coding on Haskell.

If this is true, then using StackOverflow to *learn from scratch* will not help you very much, imho.

You should instead refer to some kind of book/resource to learn the basics. [*Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a good and easy to read book for learning Haskell.

As regards programming in general, since Haskell is functional and, therefore, extremely different from the languages that common programming books use to teach you programming (C/C++, Java, Python, ...), I ***conjecture*** that starting with the book I linked without a previous knowledge of programming might not be that catastrofic; maybe it could be an advantage too.

Comment: This is great advice for learning Haskell - but I'm not sure it belongs in an answer as it doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, in this case you should probably flag it as NAA. On the other hand, given the nature of the question (_I ask the question because I "know nothing about it"_), I think I am giving the OP a good answer in the sense that I'm guiding him to a resource that will answer this question, and many other trivial questions that the OP would ask if he was to keep using SO as a place to ask "explain to me why 2 + 2 = 4" questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28553452)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, happier now?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
markToGrade :: Mark -> Grade 
markToGrade mark
 | mark >= 80 && mark <= 100 = HighDistinction
 | mark >= 70 && mark < 80 = Distinction
 | mark >= 60 && mark < 70 = Credit
 | mark >= 50 && mark < 60 = Pass
 | mark >=  0 && mark < 50 = Fail
 | otherwise = error "markToGrade: Not a valid mark"
```